# How to add advanced CKEditor dialog tab for iframe?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;
use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;

/**
 * Defines the "dialogadvtab" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "dialogadvtab",
 *   label = @Translation("dialogadvtab"),
 *   module = "custom_ckeditor"
 * )
 */
class CustomDialogAdvTab extends CKEditorPluginBase {

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile().
   */
  public function getFile() {
    return drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_ckeditor') . '/js/ckeditor_plugins/dialogadvtab/plugin.js';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getButtons() {
    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return [];
  }

}
```

This is my code which is not working.
This file I have added in drupal8/modules/custom/custom_ckeditor/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin as CustomDialogAdvTab.php

Same like, adding fakeobjects addon for iframe, CustomFakeObjects.php

```
namespace Drupal\custom_ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginBase;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "fakeobjects" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "fakeobjects",
 *   label = @Translation("FakeObjects"),
 * )
 */
class CustomFakeObjects extends CKEditorPluginBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFile() {
    return drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_ckeditor') . '/js/ckeditor_plugins/fakeobjects/plugin.js';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getButtons() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

in page view-source, I can able to see fakeobjects plugin.js where as advanced tab plugin has not been loaded

If I try to add plugin via CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load, like below,

```
        CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(basePath + modulePath + '/js/ckeditor_plugins/fakeobjects/plugin.js');
        CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(basePath + modulePath + '/js/ckeditor_plugins/dialogadvtab/plugin.js');
```

fakeobjects/plugin.js file is loading but not dialogadvtab/plugin.js, file is in place, both have same permission, no error to debug.

Comment: What do you expect the code to do? What does it actually do? How have you used it? Without that info it's going to be basically impossible to provide you with an answer

Comment: Hey hey, welcome to Drupal Answers again! Your question lacks crucial information. What are you trying to do exactly? What is happening right now exactly? Any error output? What does "not working" mean? Please update that question to provide exact context. As we simply don't provide free debugging services here.

Comment: Updated my question, please have a look into that

Comment: Did you install the FakeObjects bridge module? I am not sure why you need "CustomFakeObjects" class at all. https://www.drupal.org/project/fakeobjects

Comment: @Kevin, Am not using Drupal Fakeobjects module, instead am using fackobjects plugin from ckeditor https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/fakeobjects , also fakeobjects is working fine as I can able to use basic iframe in CKEditor, my query is, I want to use advanced tab for iframe which I need to integrate https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialogadvtab for that, and this is not working

Comment: The module exists and doesn’t require you to write any code for it.

Comment: Drupal module exists only for basic IFrame plugin and not for advanced tab, so I am integrating it, please try to understand the question, am not asking for IFrame plugin as its working, am asking for Advanced tab integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement getButtons()

```
public function getButtons() {
    return [
      'dialogadvtab' => [
        'label' => $this->t('AdvancedTabDialog'),
        'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/icon/dialogadvtab/dialogadvtab.png',
      ],
    ];
  }
```

Then admin/config/content/formats add button to your ckeditor. 
You can find any icon 16x16 png on this site https://www.iconfinder.com

[image: AdvancedTabDialog]

Comment: AdvancedTabDialog , there is no button configuration, its just a plugin same like fakeobjects to implement some extra features, expecting a working answer for Durpal8

Comment: Have you tried this? Recenly I have added AdvancedTabDialog like this

Comment: I have not tried this because, the plugin which I have downloaded from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialogadvtab  have only plugin.js file.  There is no icons

Comment: You could use any icon.

Comment: You are right, after adding the icon, now advanced tab is showing-up, but the design breaks, so, in ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialogadvtab , there is no information/description that we need to add icon for this plugin... anyway, thanks @Mokys

Answer (score 0):

There is a Drupal contrib module [CKEditor Advanced Tab](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_advanced_tab).

Check the README.md file to add the js plugin to your composer.

And don't forget to add the button (look the same as the link button) to your toolbar, even if this is not logical. The button will not be show when you edit content later.